# Hibernate's @ManyToMany making index with unique constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a @ManyToMany relationship annotation that's generating an undesired index with a unique constraint. I'm not sure how to prevent this. Here's what my annotation looks like:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ab_join_table",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="entity_b_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = false),
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "none", inverseName = "none")
private Set<EntityB> entities = new HashSet<>();
```

Basically, I have a table EntityA and EntityB that have a many-to-many relationship and use a join table to bridge the relationship. Nothing special. The problem is, the UID isn't desired to be unique and I don't want this unique constraint added! It's added as an index

```
"uk_5u10jim5rbm0dggygeebnr6ve" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (uid)
```

How do I prevent this?

My column (that the index is created on undesireably) is annotated as follows:

```
@Column(name="uid", nullable = false, unique = false)
private String uid;
```

Comment: I don't get it, I'm trying to figure out why you're getting the unique constraint, specifying all those attributes `unique = false` and `foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))` shouldn't even be necessary, If you're using hibernate's auto generate feature turn it off (this feature is not accurate) and instead create your schema manually and check If by adding something to the table would cause a unique constraint violation.

Comment: If UID *isn't desired to be unique* why would you use it as your `joinColumn` and `inverseJoinColumn`? You need unique identifiers from both tables (entities) in your bridge table in order to create its composite primary key.

Comment: @DanielArechiga I know those aren't necessary, but I added them as part of my question to show it's still happening even explicitly set as false. We are using hbm2ddl.auto with a value of update...

Comment: @rosenthal I have the exact same problem. Any solution?

Comment: @rosenthal same here! Did someone find something?